# Primefaces binding Bean with form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm developing an application with primefaces, I´m trying to map my form with my Bean of User but i can't, this is my code:

```xml
<h:form>
   <p:panelGrid columns="2">   
      <h:outputLabel for="usuario" value="Usuario: *"/>  
       <h:inputText id="usuario" binding="#{beanPrueba.user.usuario}"></h:inputText>

       <h:outputLabel for="contrasena" value="Contraseña: *" />  
       <h:inputSecret id="contrasena"></h:inputSecret>

     <f:facet name="footer"> 
     <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check" value="Entrar" ajax="false"
                 action="#{beanPrueba.prueba()}"/>
     </f:facet> 
   </p:panelGrid> 
 </h:form>
```

Backing bean:

```java
@ManagedBean(name = "beanPrueba")
@SessionScoped
public class BeanLogin {

private Usuario user = new Usuario();

public Usuario getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Usuario user) {
    this.user = user;
}

 public void prueba()
{
    try {
        //my code
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

in my bean declare a object of User, I'm using the object user for map my form with my bean but I get an error when map to bean with my form

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 4):

You are using binding attribute completely wrong. In your case you shouldn't use binding, replace it with `value` attribute. `binding` is used if you want to bind whole component with some `UIComponent` property of your backing bean, and manage component attributes programmatically. Value provide connection between component value, and some backing bean property.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's also wrong the syntax of method calling, it should be

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check" value="Entrar" ajax="false"
             action="#{beanPrueba.prueba}"/>
```

without parenthetis.